Why do photochemical simulations use linear interpolation in internal coordinates?
Is anyone here familiar with theoretical photochemistry? If the linear interpolation (LIIC) does not represent the true minimum-energy pathway (MEP), why do I see a lot of papers using it to simulate a photochemical reaction? There are also other interpolation schemes such as IDPP and geodesic interpolation, but I don't see these used in the literature.
From what I understand, people just interpolate the structures and then do some wave function theory calculation to calculate the energies and then make conclusions; but I don't see the physical significance of this if the pathway is not the MEP in the first place.

I personally have not seen many papers that use LIIC, if at all. I personally usually use relaxed scans, and some of my colleagues use IRC or scans along normal modes. Could it be that the papers that you read were relatively old, or they come from a certain sub-field where people are unaware of IDPP?

Is this a relatively old paper? It's from 2014. https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.23463.
I am trying to do a similar calculation with a different compound. I initially tried a relaxed scan but I personally didn't like the trajectory as there were more degrees of freedom I may need to constrain. I opted for a geodesic interpolation, but I haven't found papers that used that method.
Here is a fairly recent paper that also used LIIC: 10.1038/s41467-020-16667-x
